# Check a particular String against multiple startsWith prefix in Android

Tags: java, android

I am working on Credit Card Type detection by Number enetered by User in Android.
Now, [Dankort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dankort) cards starts with prefix "4571" and [VISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Inc.) cards starts with prefix "4".

While start enteting number, If user starts with 4 then I do not want to show a TYPE because it may be a Dankort or may be VISA. now if second entered digit is other than 5, then I want to show VISA. And if user enteres 457, then also I will still not show any TYPE. and if user enters 4571, then I will show Dankort.

Basically, I want character by character search, but I am not able to do that

Cards startsWith prefixs are stored in an ArrayList. What I have tried so far is.
Iterate through a prefix list and check for user entered number startsWith. If user enetered number is startsWith the prefix provided in list. Then I add it to one temporary list and if temporary list size is equal to 1, then I believe that card type is found.

For exmaple :  see a below code. It is only for a demo purpose

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add("4");
list.add("4570");

List<String> matchList = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    if(cardNumber.startsWith(list.get(i))) {
        matchList.add(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

But this is not working as if I start typing and type only "4", then also it showing VISA card. Let me know, If you need any more clearity

Comment: [**Auto-completion:** `AutoCompleteTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView) is what you want, for prefixes (startsWith), 4 to "Visa". 4571 to "Dankort". If pressing 4 already displays 2 solutions to select from, that is not bad.

Answer (score 0):

First Globally define Type:

```
String Type= "^(4571)" +              // matches leading 4571 (Dankort)
            "|^(4(?:[0-46-9]" +       // matches leading 4 followed by not 5 (Visa)
            "|5(?:[0-68-9]" +   // matches leading 45 followed by not 7 (Visa)
            "|7[02-9])))" + // matches leading 457 followed by not 1 (Visa)
            "|^(5)" +                 // matches leading 5 (MasterCard)
            "|^(6)" +                 // matches leading 6 (Discover Card)
            "|^(37)" +                // matches leading 37 (American Express)
            "|^(38)";                 // matches leading 38 (Diners Club)
```

then

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                Matcher m = Pattern.compile(Type).matcher(s);
                if (! m.find()) {
                    // unknown
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Unknown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (m.start(1) != -1) {
                    // Dankort
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Dankort", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (m.start(2) != -1) {
                    // Visa
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Visa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (m.start(3) != -1) {
                    // MasterCard
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "MasterCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (m.start(4) != -1) {
                    // Discover Card
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Discover Card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (m.start(5) != -1) {
                    // American Express
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "American Express", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (m.start(6) != -1) {
                    // Diners Club
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Diners Club", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // unknown
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Unknown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you please modify your code as the loop I have taken in question. See its easy to check like that. But 4571 and 4 are just example I written here to show the scenario. Actually I will not know the prefix in advance.

Comment: Please check the above answer..In my case it's working like charm.@BhargavThanki

Answer (score 0):

You can first define the number starts with 4. Then define 4571 as Dankort and others as Visa.

Like Below:

```
if(input.getText().toString().startsWith("4")){
   if(input.getText().toString().startsWith("4571") && input.getText().toString().startsWith("457") && input.getText().toString().startsWith("45")){
        //Dankort
     } 
   else {
       // Visa
       }

}
```

Now it until the user type first 4 digits, it will not decide the card.

Comment: If I type 457 then It will show me a VISA card but I do not know yet that 4th digit of user would be 4571 or anything else. In this scenario this code fails. Thanks for the help

Comment: then why don't you add some more logics? check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a regular expression like this:

```regex
^(4571)|^(4(?:[0-46-9]|5(?:[0-68-9]|7[02-9])))
```

If group 1 matches, then it's a Dankort.
If group 2 matches, then it's a Visa.
Otherwise it's unknown.

As code:

```java
String regex = "^(4571)" +              // matches leading 4571 (Dankort)
              "|^(4(?:[0-46-9]" +       // matches leading 4 followed by not 5 (Visa)
                    "|5(?:[0-68-9]" +   // matches leading 45 followed by not 7 (Visa)
                        "|7[02-9])))" + // matches leading 457 followed by not 1 (Visa)
              "|^(5)" +                 // matches leading 5 (MasterCard)
              "|^(6)" +                 // matches leading 6 (Discover Card)
              "|^(37)" +                // matches leading 37 (American Express)
              "|^(38)";                 // matches leading 38 (Diners Club)
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex ).matcher(cardNumber);
if (! m.find()) {
    // unknown
} else if (m.start(1) != -1) {
    // Dankort
} else if (m.start(2) != -1) {
    // Visa
} else if (m.start(3) != -1) {
    // MasterCard
} else if (m.start(4) != -1) {
    // Discover Card
} else if (m.start(5) != -1) {
    // American Express
} else if (m.start(6) != -1) {
    // Diners Club
} else {
    // unknown
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing credit card type as an `enum`.

For selecting the right type, iterate all of them, and find a card type with matching prefix. However, if the credit card number is short and matches part of a prefix, defer matching until the credit card number is longer.

```java
public enum CreditCardType {
    AmericanExpress("37"),
    Dankort("4571"),
    DinersClub("38"),
    DiscoverCard("6"),
    MasterCard("5"),
    Visa("4"),
    ;

    private final String prefix;

    private CreditCardType(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public static Optional<CreditCardType> fromCreditCardNumber(String ccNumber) {
        if (ccNumber == null || ccNumber.isEmpty())
            return Optional.empty();
        CreditCardType candidate = null;
        for (CreditCardType cardType : values()) {
            if (ccNumber.length() < cardType.prefix.length() && cardType.prefix.startsWith(ccNumber))
                return Optional.empty(); // incomplete prefix, so cannot determine type yet
            if (ccNumber.startsWith(cardType.prefix))
                candidate = cardType;
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(candidate);
    }
}
```